# (globally) lock Interface Orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, locking, uiinterfaceorientation

Is there a way to lock the interface orientation in my app *other than* the usual shouldRotate... method?
I'm looking for a way to lock the current orientation similar to the lock-button of ios, which will override all app settings and lock the orientation. Is there possibly a way to even set the iOS orientation log progamatically?
If not, should it be sufficient to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in *one* visible view to block rotation for the whole app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which orientations are supported by your app in the info.plist, using the key:

```
 UISupportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Comment: No, it can't.  Re-reading your question, I wonder if you don't need some sort of singleton that returns currently allowed orientations, and all of your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation methods should just call that.

Comment: Could work too. S there is no way of accessing the operating systems orientation lock?

Comment: Not that I know of (sorry, that's vague).